# When adding event listener to a batch of objects in Javascript, can I use a for loop instead switch statement to specify different scenarios?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, switch-statement, addeventlistener, anonymous-function

So basically I am trying to play different sound files for different buttons when clicked. I wrote a switch statement and it worked. I tried to simplify the code and write a for loop instead. However, the for loop doesn't work. Is it bcs there is the i variable in for loop's scenarios?

for loop

```
var soundFiles = ["crash.mp3", "kick-bass.mp3", "snare.mp3", "tom-1.mp3", "tom-2.mp3", "tom-3.mp3", "tom-4.mp3"]

for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var soundSrc = "sounds/" + soundFiles[i];
    var audio = new Audio(soundSrc);
    audio.play();
  });
}
```

switch statement

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    switch (this.innerHTML) {
      case "w":
        var crash = new Audio("sounds/crash.mp3");
        crash.play();
        break;
      case "a":
        var kick = new Audio("sounds/kick-bass.mp3");
        kick.play();
        break;
      case "s":
        var snare = new Audio("sounds/snare.mp3");
        snare.play();
        break;
      case "d":
        var tom1 = new Audio("sounds/tom-1.mp3");
        tom1.play();
        break;
      case "j":
        var tom2 = new Audio("sounds/tom-2.mp3");
        tom2.play();
        break;
      case "k":
        var tom3 = new Audio("sounds/tom-3.mp3");
        tom3.play();
        break;
      case "l":
        var tom4 = new Audio("sounds/tom-4.mp3");
        tom4.play();
        break;
      default:
        console.log(this.innerHTML)

    }
    var soundSrc = "sounds/" + soundFiles[i];
    var audio = new Audio(soundSrc);
    audio.play();
  });
}
```

Comment: You could set up all the audio on page load and then only play when needed?

Answer (score 1):

First, call `.querySelectorAll()` **once**:

```
let drums = document.querySelectorAll(".drum");
```

Then in your loop, use `let` instead of `var`:

```
for (let i = 0; i < drums.length; i++) {
  drums[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var soundSrc = "sounds/" + soundFiles[i];
    var audio = new Audio(soundSrc);
    audio.play();
  });
}
```

By using `let` instead of `var` for the loop index `i`, you get a distinct `i` for each iteration of the loop. With `var`, the variable is scoped to the enclosing function, so things don't work because it ends up being equal the the array length when the click events actually happen.

In browsers other than IE, you can make it even easier:

```
drums.forEach(function(drum, i) {
  drum.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var soundSrc = "sounds/" + soundFiles[i];
    var audio = new Audio(soundSrc);
    audio.play();
  });
});
```